# Mysql Group By 24 hour intervals

Tags: mysql, group-by

How can I Group the records of the table Test by time interval, beginning everyday at 19:00 and ending on the next day at 18:59?

Table: Test

```
id  creation_date   name
1   2014-01-01      17:52:27    a
2   2014-01-01      18:50:00    b
3   2014-01-01      19:00:00    c
4   2014-01-03      18:59:00    e
5   2014-01-03      12:00:00    f
```

Desired result is:

```
Interval                                    Number of Occurrences
2013-31-31 19:00:00 - 2014-01-01 18:59:59   2
2014-01-01 19:00:00 - 2014-01-02 18:59:59   1
2014-01-02 19:00:00 - 2014-01-03 18:59:59   1
2014-01-03 19:00:00 - 2014-01-04 18:59:59   1
```

Comment: Title says 12 hour intervals but text implies 24 hour intervals?

Comment: Edited. Thks Digital Chris.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT MIN(creation_date), MAX(creation_date), COUNT(*) AS Occurrences 
FROM test
GROUP BY DATE(DATE_SUB(creation_date, INTERVAL 19 HOUR))
```

Working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa7583/6

For the formatting part, use this:

```
SELECT CONCAT( CONCAT(DATE(DATE_SUB(creation_date, INTERVAL 19 HOUR)),' 19:00:00') , ' - ' , CONCAT(DATE(DATE_ADD(creation_date, INTERVAL 5 HOUR)), ' 18:59:00') ) AS Interval, COUNT(*) AS Occurrences 
FROM test
GROUP BY DATE(DATE_SUB(creation_date, INTERVAL 19 HOUR))
```

Comment: Thk you for your interest. Your query doesn't return the desired result. The idea is not to subtrat 19H to each datetime (cause they can bt 13:13, 23:13, 13:00, etc.), but to fit each record on a interval that begins on that day at 19:00 and ends on the next day at 18:59.

Comment: @user1391581 I think the query works as expected, please take a look at the working query at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa7583/6 I have used the sample data that you have provided. Let me know what is wrong with the output which is shown on that sqlfiddle (link).

Comment: I've seen it. The expected Number of Occurrences is 2, 1, 1, 1. Not: 2, 1, 2.

Comment: @user1391581 Based on your sample data, last 2 rows (ID 4 & 5) both lie in the same interval of `2014-01-02 19:00:00 - 2014-01-03 18:59:59` because last row has time 12:00:00 which comes before 18:59:00. So 2, 1, 2 is correct.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I meant 2014-01-04 12:00:00 on id = 5. Thks a lot. +1!

Comment: Hi again. The interval is wrong. Is returning:
Interval
2014-01-01 19:00:00 - 2014-01-01 18:59:00
2014-01-01 19:00:00 - 2014-01-01 18:59:00
2014-01-03 19:00:00 - 2014-01-03 18:59:00
2014-01-04 19:00:00 - 2014-01-04 18:59:00

Can you fix it?
Suggestion:

`SELECT CONCAT( CONCAT(DATE(DATE_SUB(creation_date, INTERVAL 19 HOUR)),' 19:00:00') , ' - ' , CONCAT(DATE(DATE_ADD(creation_date, INTERVAL 5 HOUR)), ' 18:59:00') ) AS Interval, COUNT(*) AS Occurrences 
FROM test
GROUP BY DATE(DATE_SUB(creation_date, INTERVAL 19 HOUR))`

Comment: @user1391581 yup, you are right on the mark. Your suggested change looks good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
 select count( distinct( q0.made_date )) from
 (
     select (date_sub( cast( concat( creation_date, " ", name ) as datetime )), -19, HOUR ) as made_date ) 
 ) as q0
```

(haven't tried this in a fiddle but the idea is to normalize the date back to midnight and then group by dates )

Comment: Thk you for your interest. Your query doesn't return the desired result. The idea is not to subtrat 19H to each datetime (cause they can bt 13:13, 23:13, 13:00, etc.), but to fit each record on a interval that begins on that day at 19:00 and ends on the next day at 18:59.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the purpose of the desired query :\