# Group by two different date and time mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to generate a report based on `date and time`.

My database table has payments recorded with `amount` and `created datetime`.

And, I need to group data like sum of payments from `9:30pm` yesterday to `9:29pm` today

(i.e) instead of group by date(created_date). And then records between these `time range`.

I have the last two months records in my payments table.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: So you basically want to group by the date plus an additional 9:30 “offset” applied … so look at the date- and time functions of MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Just add 2.5 hours to each date/time.  This is most easily represented at 150 minutes:

```
group by date(created_date + interval 150 minute)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers.

I ended up with this one - group by 24 hours

```
SELECT CONCAT( CONCAT(DATE(DATE_SUB(created, INTERVAL '21:30' HOUR_MINUTE)),
' 21:30:00') , ' - ' ,CONCAT(DATE(DATE_ADD(created, INTERVAL '2:30' HOUR_MINUTE)),
'  21:29:59') ) AS tintin, COUNT(*)  FROM test GROUP BY DATE(DATE_SUB(created, 
INTERVAL '21:30' HOUR_MINUTE)) ORDER BY DATE(created) DESC ;
```

got some idea from here

[Mysql Group By 24 hour intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910002/mysql-group-by-24-hour-intervals)