# MySQL Group by specific 24 hour interval

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table, with timestamps values in each row. My objective is to sum values of the amount column, and group by a custom 24 hour interval, starting from 05:30:00 every day.

input:

```
timestamp                 amount
--------------            ------
2015-01-19 08:30:12       4
2015-01-19 15:37:40       2
2015-01-20 01:57:38       2
2015-01-20 07:10:07       4
2015-01-20 22:10:38       2
2015-01-21 08:35:55       4
```

expected:

```
interval                                      SUM(amount)
-------------                                 -----------
2015-01-19 05:30:00 - 2015-01-20 05:30:00     8
2015-01-20 05:30:00 - 2015-01-21 05:30:00     6 
2015-01-21 05:30:00 - 2015-01-22 05:30:00     4
```

I have tried implementing the solution(s) presented here [Groupinginto interval of 5 minutes within a time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range) and here [Mysql Group By 24 hour intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910002/mysql-group-by-24-hour-intervals) - but without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by subtracting 5.5 hours and aggregating by the date:

```
select date_add(date(timestamp - interval (5*60 + 30) minute), interval (5*60 + 30)  minute) as interval_start,
       date_add(date(timestamp - interval (5*60 + 30) minute), interval (24*60 + 5*60 + 30)  minute) as interval_end,
       count(*) as cnt
from t
group by date(timestamp - interval (5*60 + 30) minute)
order by interval_start;
```

Comment: excellent answer. Interval is something I will investigate further. I had a small issue with line 4 -  "from table t", where "from t" was enough :)